# Doxygen extracts data types and displays wrong associativity

Tags: uml, doxygen

After going through the whole Doxyfile I still was not able to find an option to prevent doxygen to create class diagrams like:

[image: See Doxygen output]

Where I'd like the members to be included in the class diagram with their type, in the above case:

[image: Manual class diagram]

Additionally, doxygen shows the associativity wrong:
In the case of the simple code

```
class A{};
class B{
A a; };
```

We expect something like

[image: Correct UML-class diagram]

But doxygen creates:

[image: this.]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I:
1) Show the private class variables in the class itself
2) Get the right object relation: Composition instead of aggregation (I know I can change the ouptut html manually, but this is rather inconvenient)

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding the clarification in a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So some source code and the settings you made compared to the standard Doxyfile.

Comment: You have now 2 questions in the question. 1) regarding the data types this can get messy quite fast (especially with multiple arguments). Feel free to file an enhancement issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new Do you have any references where this is used / formalized ? 2) regarding the use of the symbols, best to file a bug report at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new.

Comment: Actually, I am not the first one noticing doxygen produces not the desired UML output, more concrete the issue with aggregation and composition is known:  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/2646